# What's "the most right" symbol to use for "defined to be equal to"?

Tags: soft-question, notation

What's the most used symbol for "defined to be equal to", at least in your experience (and I'm sure there are a lot of experienced people here)? Also, which one do you think is the "the most right" of them, in the sense of making the most amount of sense (no pun intended)? The ones I frequently see in literature, papers and articles on the Web are '$\equiv$', '$:=$' and '$=_{def}$'. The first one I come across a lot, though for me it's still "reserved" for modular arithmetic. The second one seems like it's come straight out of some programming language and the last one I frequently see in philosophy papers on logic and the like. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Personally, I use $:=$, mainly because $\equiv$ is used for other things and $=_{def}$ just doesn't look very pretty to me.  There other ones, such as $\triangleq$.

Comment: I use $:=$, with $\stackrel{\text{def}}=$ denoting that I _apply_ a definition to get an equality. $\equiv$ is actually "equivalent to" or "congruent to" so it is the most ambiguous.

Comment: All notations make an equal amount of sense to all others; this question is just asking which you prefer aesthetically.

Comment: @vadim123 It's still worth to point out possible ambiguities. cf $\equiv$ for a lot of other usages, among them $1 \equiv 4 \pmod 3$

Comment: I feel like the question should have been asked in the chat. What do you think?

Comment: I use the symbol ":=" when I have to, but usually just writing something like, "Define/Set/Put/Write $A = k[X]/(X^2 + 3)$" works perfectly well.

Answer (score 13):

$$:=$$ is the commonest symbol to denote "is equal by definition."

Note that $$\equiv$$ is used to denote an algebraic identity: this means that the equation is true for all permitted values of its variables. Rarely, however, it may denote a definition, so it's best to use this symbol only for congruences or identities.

In short: $$:=$$ is the most widespread (presumably as it's the easiest to typeset) "by definition" symbol .

Other symbols used to denote a definition include $$\stackrel{\triangle}= \quad , \stackrel{\text{def}}= \quad, \stackrel{\cdot}= \quad .$$

Whilst there's no amibguity in the latter three symbols, you try typing `\stackrel{\triangle}=` every single time you make a definition, as opposed to the much-shorter `:=`. You'll then see why the latter of these two is most widespread in this context.

Comment: But it still is quite an ugly typographical construction, don't you agree? It looks like I'm writing a program instead of doing math...

Comment: It's better than the god-awful $=_{def}$. Without getting into any debates about which is prettiest, the commonest symbol is $:= .$

Comment: I really feel a strong urge to hire a typographer for them to invent a pretty symbol for this, I really do.

Comment: Not everybody agrees with this. For example read the end of this page on J. Milne's website: 
http://www.jmilne.org/math/words.html

Comment: I share Milne's sentiment of being careful not to import too many bad habits from computer scientists, though I think ":=" is not that bad.

Comment: What is your evidence for claiming that “$:=$ is the commonest symbol”?

Comment: @MJD From experience, reading textbooks, books, Wikipedia and whatnot.

Comment: It's probably most common with computer scientists.

Comment: I've rarely, if ever, seen a math textbook use ":=". I think $\stackrel{def}=$ is by far the most common.

Comment: @Prometheus Not from my experience. Anyway, both have the same level of ambiguity, whereas $\equiv$, for example, is used commonly to denote two different things (congruences and identities).

Comment: @Prometheus Also, I'm not sure what your point is about J. Milne's comment. I didn't mention " we define $A:=B$".

Comment: @MJD Also, the fact that Wikipedia lists the symbol $:=$ first under "by definition." I'm not saying that this is categorical proof of anything, but if you look at other symbols with less-common counterparts, the commoner symbols are listed earlier on in the list.

Comment: That's only part of his comment. He says he personally considers it to be ugly CS jargon.

Comment: I have rarely seen := in a math. textbook.

Comment: @Prometheus I've got six analysis books on my shelf.  Every single one of them uses ":=" at least once. Considering authors tend to use consistent notation throughout their texts I believe it's pretty far spread among mathematicians, too.

Comment: I use `\triangleq` instead of `\stackrel{\triangle}=` for $\triangleq$. I am not sure if it is bare LaTeX of a part of some package, e.g., AMS. But it works here.

Answer (score 7):

One advantage of $:=$ is that it's assymetric, meaning you can distinguish the thing being defined and the definition.

Comment: I agree, but '$=_{def}$' has this property too.

Comment: That's true, but as others have said, that is less pretty and harder to type.

Comment: Even though it's a bit harder to type, still, I consider '$:=$' to be quite ugly, and definitely uglier than '$=_{def}$' (read the comments under @alexqwx's answer).

Comment: Regarding the asymmetry, the object being defined is the one closer to the colon (e.g., to the left-hand side of $:=$). Very rarely, I see $=:$, where the object being defined is at the right-hand side.

Answer (score 4):

**All of the above**. The most common one however is $ := $. The symbol $\equiv$ is usually used to denote a logical equivalence. The symbol $\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}=$ should just be exiled along with $\div$.

Ultimately, the symbol you choose is a matter of personal preference. I personally use $:=$.

Comment: Well, I've upvoted, but in my opinion $\div$ is very pretty (not that I would use it while actually doing math, God forbid :D)

Comment: Ah, the fables division symbol...I wonder when the last time I used that was...what's the $\LaTeX$ command for it?

Comment: @Nishant, I had to search for it lol. Its \div.

Comment: I have rarely seen := in a math. textbook.