# Final value of a recursion

Tags: limits, finite-differences, nonlinear-dynamics, discrete-time

**Problem**

Given $p_1, \sigma > 0$, consider the following recursion
\begin{equation*}
p_{i}=(1-L_i)p_{i-1} \qquad i=2,\dots,k
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
L_i \triangleq \frac{p_{i-1}}{p_{i-1}+\sigma}
\end{equation*}
I would like to compute the final value $p_k$ as $k\to \infty$.

**My attempt**

To be honest, due to its non-linearity, I don't know how to analyze the current recursion.
The only thing that comes to my mind is the following: regardless the values of $p_{i-1}$ and $\sigma$, we have $L_i \in[0,1]$ if $p_{i-1}$ stay non-negative. Under this conjecture,
we have the two limit cases in which $L_i\triangleq 0$ and $L_i \triangleq 1$. The evolution of $p_i$ is then confined between this two cases.

- $L_i \triangleq 1$ leads to $p_i = 0$, so in this case the limit value is zero;
- $L_i \triangleq 0$ leads to $p_i = p_{i-1}$, so in this case the limit value is $p_1$.

Based on this, I would say that $p_i$ is confined between $0$ and $p_1$ for all $i$. However, my argument is far from rigorous and does not provide a clear answer to my problem.

**EDIT**

Since
\begin{equation*}
1-L_i = \frac{\sigma}{p_{i-1}+\sigma}
\end{equation*}
it follows from $p_1, \sigma >0$ that $L_i\geq 0$, so that $p_i\geq 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: You might compute $p_2$, $p_3$, $p_4$ by hand, using $p_i = \frac{\sigma p_{i-1}}{\sigma + p_{i-1}}$ and simplify.  There is a very evident pattern here.  The resulting sequence of rational expressions has a fixed numerator and monotonically strictly increasing denominator...

Comment: What is the = with a triangle over it? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: @mpear617 : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944757/whats-the-most-right-symbol-to-use-for-defined-to-be-equal-to

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\frac1{p_i}=\frac1{p_{i-1}}+\frac1\sigma.$$

Comment: @Dominique Oh yes it does "provide an answer to the question"! This hint completely solves the problem. I left only the final step to the OP, to let him the pleasure to discover it. (What makes you believe this answer was a "critique or a request for clarification"?) @ the two voters for deletion: please explain your reasons, or remove your vote once you understood it was inappropriate.